# Non Recursive Merge Sort Skipping

Tags: c++

I am attempting to sort an array of numbers using natural merge sort. I have an array that these numbers in exact order(9,2,129,921,38,31,10,219,27,45) when I use my merge sort function I get(2,9,10,21,27,45,129,38,219,921), as you can see i am very close to getting it to sort but it seems as if it  is partly sorting it. I can't seem to find whats wrong with my code, any suggestions?

```
void merge(int *a, int size, int low, int high, int mid)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int *c = new int[size];
    i = low;
    k = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
        {
           c[k] = a[i];
           k++;
           i++;
         }
       else
       {
           c[k] = a[j];
           k++;
           j++;
       }
}
while (i <= mid)
{
    c[k] = a[i];
    k++;
    i++;
}
while (j <= high)
{
    c[k] = a[j];
    k++;
    j++;
}
for (i = low; i < k; i++)
 {
    a[i] = c[i];
  }
}
void naturalMS(int * a, int s)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < s; i *= 2)
    {
       for(int low = 0; low < s- i; low += o)
       {
           merge(a,s,low,s-1,low+i-1);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start some actual debugging. Create a function that prints out the contents of an array and add system outputs for every important position in the program, like when a recursive call is made. Print out the manipulated arrays before and after each action. Watch out for which action your algorithm fails. Btw, you should really really use std::vector instead of arrays.